# Video in the background does not start at the beginning but only when passing the connection page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am on a .NET C # project in which I am using Angular TS but also HTML CSS.
On my login page I have a video in the background which is supposed to launch as soon as I open but it is not.
The video starts when I log in and then I come back to the home page. I checked the google doc and [lots](https://forum.alsacreations.com/topic-1-81836-1-Video-qui-ne-se-lance-pas-au-demarrage-de-la-page.html) of [other](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/) [sites](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_muted.asp) that talk about muted but I'm using the property well ...
The video lasts 17 seconds and weighs 6.03 mb, height 720 width 1280

Here is my code

```
<div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <video muted autoplay  loop style="height: 100vh;
                        width: 100vw;
                        object-fit: cover;
                        position: fixed;
                        left: 0;
                        right: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        bottom: 0;
                        z-index: -1;"

               id="background-video"
               src="assets/truckbackground.mp4">
        </video>
```

And the console
[image]

Comment: Look at the javascript console. Maybe it will say autoplay is blocked by policy

Comment: I added the console to the post but I don't see any google locking, on mozilla my backgroud starts up on its own.